# Search for all occurances of a string only in the current file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I'm using Eclipse PDT. Is there a way to search and/or highlight occurrances of a string in the currently active file (or editor) **only**, not the whole project or workspace?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found away:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
2. Open the *File Search* tab
3. Within the *Scope* group select *Resource in active editor*
4. Click *Search* button

I'm using Eclipse version 2018-09 (4.9.0) (PDT 6.1.0)